# iphone app memory build up

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

Trying to diagnose why my game is building up memory, causing it to eventually slow down to the point of unresponsiveness. Based on previously asked questions, i think i might know what's causing it, not sure though, so i will just post what i think it might be.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(createObstacle0) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
[self performSelector:@selector(score0) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

....

-(void)createObstacle0 {
int yMin = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+190);
int yMax = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+270);
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-20, yMin + arc4random_uniform(yMax - yMin));
SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"];
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:21.5];
obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
obstacle.name = @"obstacle0";
[self addChild:obstacle];
[obstacle runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(340, startPoint.y) duration:minTime + arc4random_uniform(maxTime - minTime)]];
float randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3.0) + 0.1;
[self performSelector:@selector(createObstacle0) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];
}

-(void)score0 {

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"obstacle0" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.x > 330) {
        score++;
        scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)score];
        [node removeFromParent];
    }

}];
[self performSelector:@selector(score0) withObject:nil afterDelay:.1];
}
```

I read here that perferomSelector can cause some memory problems. For me, after playing my game just once, i can sit at the main menu and both cpu and memory will just continue to rise. No idea what's going on and appreciate all help. Is the code i have here to blame?

Comment: Have you run Instruments with either the Leaks or Allocations tool to see where the memory is being allocated?

Comment: First step is to profile the app. Run it through instruments and see where the memory is being used. Also, profile for zombies in instruments.

Comment: and perform an analyze build to reveal any potential code issues

Comment: @user1118321 I just ran the allocations in instruments and in just five minutes, my game went from a starting 6mb to almost 21mb. Here's two screen shots showing just part of it, http://postimg.org/image/fdgs4os3z/, http://postimg.org/image/t7vtntmwt/ Now i have five methods that create the obstacles in my game, is it reloading the image every time one of those methods is ran, does it not just need to load the image one time? Also, how on earth is my little score counter using 14mb of memory?

Comment: Yes, it appears to be loading the image every time you call the `createObstacle0` method. Are you using ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) or MRC (Manual Reference Counting)? If it's manual, where are you freeing the image?

Comment: @user1118321 ARC is on

Comment: @user1118321 is the [node removeFromParent] not deallocing it?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know enough about SceneKit to answer that question. I don't know if simply removing the node will free it or not.