# SKSpriteNode not releasing memory

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have five methods in my game that each create the same looking obstacle. I've ran instruments and see that for some reason, these obstacles are not releasing there memory. I'm using ARC. Here's an image of instruments,http://postimg.org/image/fdgs4os3z/. Here's my code that creates and gets rid of each obstacle,

```
-(void)createObstacle0 {
int yMin = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+190);
int yMax = (CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)+270);
CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(-20, yMin + arc4random_uniform(yMax - yMin));
SKSpriteNode *obstacle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"obstacle"];
obstacle.position = CGPointMake(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
obstacle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:21];
obstacle.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = enemyCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerCategory;
obstacle.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
obstacle.name = @"obstacle0";
[self addChild:obstacle];
[obstacle runAction:[SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(340, startPoint.y) duration:minTime +arc4random_uniform(maxTime - minTime)]];
float randomNum = arc4random_uniform(3.0) + 0.2;
[self performSelector:@selector(createObstacle0) withObject:nil afterDelay:randomNum];
}
  -(void)score0 {

[self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"obstacle0" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (node.position.x > 330) {
        score++;
        scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)score];
        [node removeFromParent];
        [node removeAllActions];
    }

}];
}
```

I really need help with this problem, because after just five minutes, the game will lock up because the memory just gets to high. All help appreciated.

EDIT: collision method

```
-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
 uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask |       contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);
if (collision == (playerCategory | enemyCategory)) {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:score forKey:@"playerScore"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    int highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"High Score"] integerValue];
    if (highScore){
        if (highScore < score){
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
        }
    }
    else{
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:score] forKey:@"High Score"];
    }

    [self removeAllChildren];

    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition fadeWithDuration:0.25];
    MGLCreateGameOverScene *scene = [MGLCreateGameOverScene sceneWithSize:self.view.bounds.size];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFill;
    [self.view presentScene:scene transition:reveal];

}

}
```

Second edit:

```
SKAction* removeObstacle = [SKAction removeFromParent];
[obstacle runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[move, removeObstacle]] completion:^{
    score++;
    scorelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)score];
}];
```

Comment: Try removing the node from parent in your collision method. Also how to you declare your collision. The method you posted adds the node and adds score.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey does my removeFromParent and removeAllActions in my score0 method not get rid of memory?

Comment: I'm not sure how the collision works in your game, but removing a node generally works when the action completes its work. Removing the node after collision or when it's task is completed is a norm. I have to say though, it is hard to offer a solution when only a portion of the code is offered. Although remove all action and remove from node should work but in this case it dies not do the job. So looking at the whole scene would offer a better view.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey Just added my collision method, but you made me think of something. You said that the node usually gets removed after its tasked is completed. The task for my obstacle is an SKAction which moves them to 340 on the x axis, but my score0 method removes the node once it passes 330, so the node never gets to 340, is this my problem? Im going to run instruments now and see if it makes a difference if i remove the node AT 340 instead of 330 or above, so the action actually gets to be completed.

Comment: You already asked this question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23209740/iphone-app-memory-build-up

Comment: That maybe your issue. Try it and let me know.

Comment: you may want to add some NSLog and breakpoints to see what code actually runs under what conditions. Log self.children.count as a quick test if node count continues to increase over time.

Comment: @XCodeMonkey Nope, still have the same problem, its like ARC is slow to work. Recent simulator, it started at 50mb, climbed to 350mb, then dropped to 100mb over the course of a hour and a half.

Answer (score -1):

i am facing the same problem and i found the best solution is to load all texture of the current SKScene in Arrays and before you transfer to another SKScene [array removeAllObjects];

it works with me but do not dismiss the current SKScene

i hope this helps you

Comment: first you make NSMutableArray fill with all textureAtlas of the Game 
and any images outside the TextureAtlas load it like this in the array 

 NSString *bgString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name] ofType:@"png"];
  UIImage *bg=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:bgString];
        texture=[SKTexture textureWithImage:bg]; [array addObject:texture]; then load it like this [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[array objectAtIndex:0];  and at the end of the SKScene remove all objects in the Array

Comment: could you take a look at my second edit, the first time i play my game, the memory stays stable, it's after the first time that the memory slowly starts to creep up. I think its because the code in the second edit does remove the node, but only if the action gets completed. If a player hits an obstacle, the scene transitions, and all the obstacles still moving across the screen don't have their action completed, thus never removed from the parent. How can i fix that?